# How to clear an unknown BIOS password from a non-recognized brand lapto?

Tags: windows, laptop, bios

I have a cheap child's laptop purchased from Amazon. The brand name is HBESTORE, which does not exist anywhere on the internet. The few search results found pointed back to Amazon, so I contacted Amazon hoping to get an email or any contact info for the HBESTORE. Nothing useful!

The issue is as soon as I power on the laptop, I get a small blue text box in the middle of the screen that says "Enter Password". I have left it blank, but after 3 attempts it says "System Locked", and under it is an 8-alphanumeric code: 31wp642x

Obviously, I need to get this code to the manufacturer so they can give me the correct password, but this HBESTORE does not seem to exist. I tried entering the code at https://bios-pw.org/ but it does nothing when I press "Get the Password", so I assume this BIOS is not compatible with this website tool.

I disassembled the laptop and took pictures of the system board if that may help. Strangely, after disconnecting the battery, the new locked BIOS code became all z's: zzzzzzzz, if that's helpful in anyway. Though after restarting the laptop again and entering 3 wrong passwords, the current final code is: 31wp642x

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Most firmware passwords cannot be reset, or specifically, without a chip programmer.

Comment: Do you really need this headache of a machine? Put it back together and return it to the seller for a full refund.

Answer (score 0):

It is most unlikely the manufacturer would enter and install an undocumented BIOS Password. Most (almost all) BIOS passwords cannot be reset by consumers (true for all the laptops I have seen).

The machine likely had a prior owner who did this.

Ask Amazon again and if you cannot get satisfaction  from the seller, return the laptop for a refund. Amazon will very most likely make good on this.